# A 16-character password consists of digits 1 through 6 and is obtained through a fair cube flip series.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A 16-character password consists of digits 1 through 6 and is obtained through a fair cube flip series. What is the number of options for getting code that each of the digits 1,2,3 appears at least once?

I thought about maybe $${3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot6^{13}}$$ but i am not even close.. 
if you have any way to solve this ill be more than happy.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @saulspatz I didnt succeed with exclusion principle.. thanks for the extremly help btw

Comment: Okay, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are $6^{16}$ possible sequences.  We want to exclude the $5^{16}$ that don't have a $1$, and also those that don't have a $2$ or $3$.  That gives us $$6^{16}-3\cdot5^{16}$$ so far.  But what about the ones that don't have two of them, say neither a $1$ nor a $2$? We've subtracted them twice, and so we have to add them back in.  Now we have $$6^{16}-3\cdot5^{16}+3\cdot4^{16}$$  Finally, we have to consider those with neither $1,2,$ nor $3$.  They've been subtracted $3$ times (one for each value) and added back in three times (once for each pair of values), so we need to to subtract them.  Final answer is 
$$6^{16}-3\cdot5^{16}+3\cdot4^{16}-3^{16}=2,376,188,090,748$$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @LorinSherry My pleasure.

Comment: just the second line im not fully understand :\ why we need to add back? 
The first line saying that the first char of the "password" can be 3 numbers(3,2 or 1), so thats why were taking 3 X 5^16 
but the next line im just dont get it

Comment: @LorinSherry Consider a sequence that is missing both $1$ and $2$.  We subtracted it once because it's missing the $1$, and then we subtracted it another time because it's missing the $2$.  It doesn't make sense to subtract the same sequence twice; we have to add those back in, so that they're only subtracted once. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle